# Android Vitals: Ignore debugging app

Tags: android, debugging

At the moment the application-crashes from the debugging version are collected in the android vitals console. Is it somehow possible, that these statistics are not going to be stored in the play console?

Maybe important: For testing i (as the developer) put myself on the list for the closed alpha testers, just for testing if the download from the play store works. After the download worked, i deleted myself from the list and leaved the alpha programm from the playstore.

But the statistics from my device were still collected. How can i delete myself from statistics-collecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after one day of testing I think I figured it out:

Just add the `debug`-Build-Type to your gradle file and define an `applicationIdSuffix` like this:

```
...
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
       ...
    }
}
...
```